# Unexpected empty space before and after ScrollView

Tags: swiftui

I'm not sure as to why there is an empty space before and after ScrollView. Could someone explain it?

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("A")
                .background(.red)
            Text("B")
                .background(.blue)
            Text("C")
                .background(.red)
            ScrollView {
                Text("D")
                    .background(.blue)
            }.background(.yellow)
            Text("E")
                .background(.red)
        }
    }
```

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VStack{}` generally has its own initialized spaces between each element.

To fix this just set `spacing:`  to 0. (code is below the image)

[image]

```
VStack(spacing: 0) { //this
             Text("A")
                 .background(.red)
             Text("B")
                 .background(.blue)
             Text("C")
                 .background(.red)
             ScrollView {
                 Text("D")
                     .background(.blue)
             }.background(.yellow)
             Text("E")
                 .background(.red)
         }
```

Comment: But even if there is a default non-zero spacing (but without scroll view there is no spacing at all because it's nil which behave similar to zero I suppose?) question is why is it only applied to ScrollView and not to other items? For example setting it to something like 10 will add spacing between all views.

Comment: Documentation says "`nil` if you want the stack to choose a default distance for each pair of subviews.". Interesting why it decides to add spacing around scrollview...